# Android LinearLayout set layout_gravity in java code

Tags: java, android, layout, layout-gravity

I have a problem on this layout :(

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cuerpo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
...
```

In java code

```
LinearLayout cuerpo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.cuerpo);

if(align){
   cuerpo.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
}else{
   cuerpo.setGravity(Gravity.NO_GRAVITY);
}
```

I need layout_gravity to be no gravity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The layout gravity you are talking about is within the `LayoutParams` of of the `LinearLayout` object. So, logically, to get this you have to follow the following steps:

1. Get the `LayoutParams` of your `LinearLayout`.
2. If you know what the `LayoutParams` are supposed to be, you can cast them (beware, this is based on **your** choice, so you must make sure it is correct!).
3. Set the `gravity` of the `LayoutParams` as you desire.

So in code this would be:

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = cuerpo.getLayoutParams(); // Step 1.
LinearLayout.LayoutParams castLayoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) layoutParams; // Step 2.
castLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL; // Step 3.
```

Or as a simple one liner that does all steps in one:

```
((LinearLayout.LayoutParams) cuerpo.getLayoutParams()).gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
```

**Please beware:**

I cannot see exactly what you are trying to do, but it does not seem correct. The type of `LayoutParams` is not the type of the `View`, but the type of `Layout` that your `View` is to reside in.

(**i.e.** like in @gincsait's reference, if I have a `Button` in a `LinearLayout`, then the `LayoutParams` of the `Button` will be of type `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. The same **cannot** be said for the `LayoutParams` of the `LinearLayout`.)